# How to share eslint file accross a team?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, eslint

### Background

I have an `eslint` file that I use across multiple Nodejs projects with my team. This file is important and I need to use it in every project, so I end up copying it over and over again.

### Problem

This is a terrible idea because If I make a change to the `eslint` file, I need to manually copy/paste it into all the other projects and sometimes I forget which projects have the updated file and which projects don't.

### Objective

My objective here would be to make it automatic. My first idea was to publish the `eslint` file in NPM, and then manage it via there.

The problem with this approach is that if I do `npm install`, NPM will place my lint file into the `node_modules` directory and thus nothing will work.

This file needs to be at the root of the project, side by side with `package.json`.

### Question

How do I share this `eslint` file across multiple projects automatically?

Comment: have you installed eslint locally to each project?  have you looked at installing eslint globally? maybe using samba or a share for the shared configs and plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer

Turns out that you can use NPM packages to share ESLint files across multiple projects and teams, which was unknown to me:

http://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/sharing-eslint-across-teams/

The official documentation details how this can be done, and which conventions to follow:

http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs#creating-a-shareable-config

Comment: This works great, btw. We created an npm module for CNTRAL's shared ESLint configuration and it worked very well across multiple projects. ESLint does a phenomenal job at including this in their core.